# load div, images and/or scripts when they come in viewport

Tags: javascript, css, load

When you see the following website: http://www.10kb.nl
You can see that some parts are loaded when they come into the viewport.

I would love to learn how to create that but now i'm wondering what kind of javascript or css3 is used for this kind of effects so I can search online for the right tutorials.

Comment: What's stopping you from taking a look at that site's source code?

Comment: It's called `lazy loading`. There are a number of plugins for it.

Comment: Hi Erwin, I see you asked this question a while ago, but I came only across it just now. I made http://10kb.nl and we used waypoint.js (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) to trigger animation based on your viewport. If you have any questions about it, please don't hesitate to send us an e-mail at info [at] 10kb [dot] nl.

Comment: @EwoutKleinsmann thank you for (still) coming back to my question :). I'm now using WOW.js combined with css3 transform effects but I definitely will checkout waypoints too! <NL> Leuke website en een erg leuke naam :)! </NL>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called WOW.js that you can use / study. It's designed for this, and doesn't have too much in the way of dependencies (it uses animate.css for the animations, and it handles the scrolling events).

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/